# Problem with bounding box in TikZ using inner sep=0pt

Tags: tikz-pgf

maybe this is a well-known problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution for it yet. The TikZ option `inner sep=0pt` at a node leads to a wrong bounding box (at least for characters or numbers as an argument). This means e.g. that nodes cannot be positioned correctly. In my minimal example I have tried to illustrate that.
Here is the code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% If the bounding boxes were correct, the two ones would have to touch each other.
\node[fill=yellow, inner sep=0pt] (one) {1};
\node[fill=red, inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] at (one.east) {1}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The Output looks like this

[image]

As you can see, the bounding boxes for the two ones are too big at the left and the right part, but too small at the upper part. The lower part fits as I would expect it. What is the reason for the bounding boxes behaving like that? I have seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048850/what-is-the-difference-between-font-bounding-box-and-glyph-bounding-box that there is a difference between font bounding box and glyph bounding box. But in neither of the two definitions it would make sense for a bounding box to cut its own content as here in the example.

Comment: Because that's the bounding box of the character as defined in the font file. There's not much you can do on that side. You could try to use negative spacing to compensate that.

Comment: Do you mean something like "inner xsep=-5pt"? Well for one character or number that would make sense, but actually I want to use the bouding box mechanism as described to position "\thechapter" in the heading of my document. As the margins on the left and right are different for different numbers (e.g. for 7 it is quite tight), I would have to change the negative spacing depending on the actual chapter number.

Comment: Yes, you would need to do it in a per-number basis. Or use another font in which the actual glyphs match their bounding boxes.

Comment: Can you tell me a font where that's the case?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know any. I tried a few I can remember and it seems that none fits perfectly. `CormorantGaramond`, though, seems to have a consistent amount of space to the sides, so the amount of `inner xsep` would be the same for all numbers: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule1sp
\makeatletter
\count@=0
\loop
\fbox{\the\count@}
\advance\count@ by 1
\ifnum\count@<10
\repeat
\end{document}`

Comment: The gap comes from `outer sep`, not `inner sep`. `\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% If the bounding boxes were correct, the two ones would have to touch each other.
\node[fill=yellow, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (one) {1};
\node[fill=red, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt, anchor=west] at (one.east) {1}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

The horizontal white space comes from the default value of the [`/pgf/outer [xy]sep`s](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/outer:sep) which is `.5\pgflinewidth` meaning the anchors would lie on the outside of a drawn border.

For an un-drawn node you want these values to be zero, i.e. `outer sep = +0pt`. However PGF/TikZ has a built-in automatism that can detect a non-drawn node and set this to zero itself by specifying

```
outer sep = auto
```

---

Regarding the vertical overlap, there's nothing PGF/TikZ can do about it. It only considers the bounding box that's reported by TeX. It doesn't know about any glyphs, characters or fonts.

Compare the `\fbox` instances that show the same.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[outer sep=auto]
\node[fill=yellow, inner sep=0pt] (one) {1};
\node[fill=red,    inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] at (one.east) {2}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.01pt}%
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}%
\fbox{1}\fbox{2}\fbox{O}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that even though you declare your node without its box drawn, this is added to the calculation of the box by adding its thickness, therefore the solution is to define for those nodes the separation equal to the width of the line by default, for this case trying several options I found that it is 0.21pt, or you can also save yourself the work and paint the line the same color as the fill.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Grid in pt units
\draw[black!30,step=1pt,line width=0.1pt] (0,0) grid (30pt,-30pt);
\draw[black!80,step=10pt,line width=0.2pt] (0,0) grid (30pt,-30pt);
\draw[|-|,line width=0.2pt] (0,0)++(0,3pt)-- ++(10pt,0) node[midway](n){};
\draw[<-] (n.center) |- ++(10pt,5pt) node [anchor=180, inner sep=0pt]{\tiny \verb+10pt+};


\node[fill=yellow, inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] (one) at (0,-10pt) {1};
\node[fill=red, inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] at (one.east) {1}; 
\node[fill=yellow,draw=red, inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west, below=10pt of one](two){2};
\node[fill=red,draw=green, inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] at (two.east) {2}; 

\node[fill=yellow,draw=red, inner sep=0.21pt, anchor=south west, right=10pt of one,line width=0pt](three){3};
\node[fill=red,draw=green, inner sep=0.21pt, anchor=west,line width=0pt] at (three.east) {3}; 

\node[fill=blue, draw=blue,inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west, below=10pt of three](four){4};
\node[fill=orange, draw=orange,inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] at (four.east) {4}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```